# Traefik v2.10 Ingress not working after updating from version 1.7

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am trying to update traefik which worked, I can see now the new dashboard, but the ingress is not working. The ingress used to work before with version 1.7

This is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myendpoint-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myendpoint
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port: 
              number: 80
      - path: /auth.html
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port: 
              number: 80
      - path: /myendpoint/api/gatekeeper
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port: 
              number: 8000
      - path: /myendpoint/api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port: 
              number: 80
```

This is what I see in the dashboard and I don't know exactly what I did wrong.

[Traefik dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2kza.png)

I already tried converting the ingress to an ingressroute, but in the dashboard it appears again as a succsesful but actually accessing the routes is not working. The pod is online, I tried to curl the service and it returns the proper content.